# Method does not exist or incorrect signature: void send(System.HttpRequest) from the type System.HttpRequest

Tags: apex, webservices, future, apex-webservice

Currently stuck at trying to send a JSON structure through web services but keep receiving the error:

Method does not exist or incorrect signature: void send(System.HttpRequest) from the type System.HttpRequest

```
public class order_web_services {

@future(callout=true)
public static void order_web_services_rest(String order_JSON){

    HttpRequest request = new HttpRequest();

    String endpoint = 'https://some_web_site.com';
    request.setEndpoint(endpoint);

    request.setMethod('POST');

    request.setBody(order_JSON);

    HttpResponse response = HttpRequest.send(request);
}}
```

I am a bit confused as to why this error keeps getting thrown. Can someone please help me out.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You instantiate an **`Http`** instance, which has the send method.

**Incorrect**

```
HttpResponse response = HttpRequest.send(request);
```

**Correct**

```
HttpResponse response = new Http().send(request);
```

The `HttpRequest` does not have this method, and please note it is an *instance* method, not `static`.